# Retrofit parsing of nested Object

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I have the following `JSON` as response:

> http://pastebin.com/Qir7eNsP

I have the `User` class

```
public class User {
private int id;
@SerializedName("count_messages")
private int countMessages;
@SerializedName("count_followers")
private int countFollowers;
@SerializedName("count_following")
private int countFollowing;
@SerializedName("date_created")
private String dateCreated;
@SerializedName("date_updated")
private String dateUpdated;
private String username, name, description, location, url, lang;
@SerializedName("fb_id")
private int fbID;
@SerializedName("tw_id")
private int twID;
```

and `Message`

```
public class Message {

private int id;
@SerializedName("date_created")
private int dateCreated;
private String title, text;
private List<String> tags;
private User user;
```

The thing I need is to receive a `List<Message>` callback from retrofit.

Should I use a converter and how do I define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know how to deal with Retrofit and have some interface like this:

```
public interface MyService {
  @GET("/getData")
  ApiResponse getData();
}
```

This object will represent retrofit response with your messages.

```
public class ApiResponse {

    Properties properties;

    public static class Properties {
        List<Message> messages;
    }
}
```

And then you can get messages by this:

```
ApiResponse apiResponse = myService.getData();
List<Message> messages = apiResponse.properties.messages;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi please check my code hope it will help you

MainActivity.java

```
private final String    api = "http://api.androidhive.info";
    private RestAdapter     adapter;
    private ApiListener     apis;
    private void getContactList()
        {
            adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint(api).build();
            apis = adapter.create(ApiListener.class);
            apis.getData(new Callback<ContactsVo>()
            {

                @Override
                public void success(ContactsVo model, Response response)
                {
                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError arg0)
                {
                    progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
```

You need to create one class for all api calls
ApiListener.java

```
public interface ApiListener
{
    @GET("/contacts") 
    public void getData(retrofit.Callback<ContactsVo> response);
}
```

You need to create respective pojo class as your need,

ContactVo.java

```
public class ContactVo
{

    private String  id;
    private String  address;
    private String  email;
    private String  name;
    private String  gender;

    public String getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getGender()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

2) ContactsVo

```
public class ContactsVo
{
     private ArrayList<ContactVo> contacts;

        public ArrayList<ContactVo> getContacts ()
        {
            return contacts;
        }

        public void setContacts (ArrayList<ContactVo> contacts)
        {
            this.contacts = contacts;
        }

}
```